# how to validate if a field is a number in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

here is snippet of a helm chart I have

```
values.yaml

# Default resource requests and limits for the pod
resources:
  cpu: "500m"
  memory: "1Gi"
```

I want to be able to validate the `cpu` field format should strictly be number+m(i.e. "500m") or number or string with only numbers

How Can I do that in Helm, as it doesn't seem to have a isnumeric/tonumeric function built in?
Thx!!

Answer (score 1):

You r correct about missing  isnumeric/tonumeric functions in Helm But you can try to use a regular expression in Helm to validate the CPU field format the way you need like below

```
{{- if not (regexMatch "[0-9]+[m]?$" .Values.resources.cpu) }}
  {{- fail "Invalid CPU format. CPU should be in the format of 'number', 'numberm', or 'numberM'." }}
{{- end }}
```

This code can be added to the template files for your Helm chart (such as deployment.yaml, service.yaml, etc.), usually inside an {{- if }} block, where you want to perform the validation.

Comment: @Howard np. Did you forget to accept this as the answer or vote Howard?